# Declaring an array without an arraylist

Tags: java, android

I got  syntax error while declaring array in android. My code looks like

```
public interface Constants extends BaseColumns {
  String s[] = new String[5];  
  s[0]="ABC";  
  s[1]="DEF";  
  s[2]="GHI";  
  s[3]="JKL";  
  s[4]="MNO";
}
```

I dont want to use arraylist

Comment: what error did you got?

Comment: please share the error

Comment: Please don't ask the same question again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495891/array-assignment-syntax-errorandroid

Comment: but i am exhausted without the solution

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2):

Try

String s[] = new String[]{"ABC","DEF","GHI"};

I think it will work.

Comment: the indexes will be there, eventhough it is not specified.

Comment: but i need to Know the index of a particular string

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] array = {"ABC", "DEF", "IJK", "LMN"  };
```

Comment: This works fine for me . But I need to do it in the above fashion because array index is required

Comment: String[] array = new String[4];
array[0] = "ABC";
array[1] = "DEF";
array[2] = "GHI";
array[3] = "JKL";

Answer (score 0):

In your the same [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495891/array-assignment-syntax-errorandroid).

Here is your full code:

```
public interface Constants extends BaseColumns {    

  String[] s = new String[5];  
  s[0]="ABC";  
  s[1]="DEF";  
  s[2]="GHI";  
  s[3]="JKL";  
  s[4]="MNO";

}
```

The error of this code is you can't write expression in declaration.

You must warp a static block:

```
public interface Constants extends BaseColumns {    

  static{
    String[] s = new String[5];  
    s[0]="ABC";  
    s[1]="DEF";  
    s[2]="GHI";  
    s[3]="JKL";  
    s[4]="MNO";
  }
}
```

A static block helps to initialize the static data members, just like constructors help to initialize instance members

Read more at http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-static-variable-methods.html#MxcOXP70VJUv22Jg.99